# react admin and AuthProvider no redirect after login

Tags: react-admin

I've notice (using some console.log) that the method  `checkAuth` is called some times only before the `login` methods and not after, so
when the login is accomplished correctly, the token is stored in the browser's local storage and at the end the method `login` returns the resolved promise,
the `checkAuth` is not anymore invoked and the page redirect is not performed by the dashboard
If then i change manually the page, it works correctly because the token is in the localstorage and the `checkAuth` method is able to check it normally

This is my AuthProvider

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    // called when the user attempts to log in
    login: ({ username, password }) => {

        username = encodeURIComponent(username);
        password = encodeURIComponent(password);

        const tokenUrl = "https://myendpoint/profili/token";
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        const config = {
            headers
        };
        const data = `username=${username}&password=${password}&grant_type=password`;
        axios.post(tokenUrl,data, config)
                                .then(response => {

                                    if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                                        throw new Error(response.statusText);
                                    }
                                    return response;
                                })
                                .then(response => {
                                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data);
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    throw new Error('Network error');
                                });
        console.log("LOGIN");

        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    // called when the user clicks on the logout button
    logout: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    // called when the API returns an error
    checkError: ({ status }) => {
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            console.log("passato in checkError");
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    // called when the user navigates to a new location, to check for authentication
    checkAuth: () => {
        console.log("CHECK AUTH");
        return localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? Promise.resolve()
            : Promise.reject();
    },
    // called when the user navigates to a new location, to check for permissions / roles
    getPermissions: () => Promise.resolve(),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did the wrong returns.
**Your login function returns** Promise.resolve() right at the moment it emits the axios HTTP POST request, **long before it gets the response** from the authentication server.

Instead replace the return by of the function by :

```
return axios.post(tokenUrl,data, config)
             .then(response =>
                   {
                     if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300)
                     {
                       throw new Error(response.statusText);
                     }
                     return response;
               }).then(response =>
               {
                 localStorage.setItem('token', response.data);
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                 throw new Error('Network error');
               });
```

**This way the Promise resolution will only happens after your authentication server responds**.